# positioning table

Tags: tables

I would like to have a table in my latex. If use this code. I am loosing a part of my table. could you please tell me how can I fix this problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{ngerman}{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\begin{document}
Interval wertvolle Informationen extrahiert werden kann, betrachten wir die Spalte 6457, in der die Ereignisse anerkannt worden sind.
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    Spalte & Ereignisse & Spalte & Ereignisse & Spalte & Ereignisse & Spalte & Ereignisse & Spalte & Ereignisse \\ \hline
    6480   & 0          & 6487   & 88         & 6494   & 26         & 6501   & 57         & 6508   & 87         \\ \hline
    6481   & 0          & 6488   & 288        & 6495   & 42         & 6502   & 89         & 6509   & 50         \\ \hline
    6482   & 0          & 6489   & 356        & 6496   & 80         & 6503   & 105        & 6510   & 72         \\ \hline
    6483   & 7          & 6490   & 92         & 6497   & 415        & 6504   & 124        & 6511   & 74         \\ \hline
    6484   & 48         & 6491   & 126        & 6498   & 343        & 6505   & 135        & 6512   & 29         \\ \hline
    6485   & 34         & 6492   & 97         & 6499   & 100        & 6506   & 30         & 6513   & 1          \\ \hline
    6486   & 45         & 6493   & 70         & 6500   & 176        & 6507   & 41         & 6514   & 0          \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can type a table with more rows and less columns.

Comment: If I do that, then I cant have this table in one page

Comment: You can rotate the table, or you can replace Spalte with S and Ereignisse with E, or you decrease font size, or or... Tell us what you want

Comment: I mean first column from 6480 to 6491, second 6492 to 6503 and third 6504 to 6514 (one row is missing in last column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the font size of your table, just add this line

```
\scriptsize
```

after the `\begin{table}[H]` line.

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion would be to stop repeating columns, and just make a single tabular with two columns, and many more rows. If you’re having a problem because the table spans multiple pages, then you could consider looking at the [`longtable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package.

If you want the tables on a single page, then here’s a suggestion: break it into multiple tables using `minipage`. The information is still quite compact and neatly laid out, but now it fits on a single page without being too small to read (which would be my concern with using `\scriptsize`).

Here's the code for my example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

Interval wertvolle Informationen extrahiert werden kann, betrachten wir die Spalte 6457, in der die Ereignisse anerkannt worden sind.

\newenvironment{mytabular}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
  \centering
  \vspace{0pt}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    Spalte & Ereignisse \\ \midrule
}{\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{mytabular}
    6480   & 0   \\
    6481   & 0   \\
    6482   & 0   \\
    6483   & 7   \\
    6484   & 48  \\
    6485   & 34  \\
    6486   & 45  \\
    6487   & 88  \\
    6488   & 288 \\
    6489   & 356 \\
    6490   & 92  \\
    6491   & 126 \\
  \end{mytabular}
  \hspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{mytabular}

    6492   & 97  \\
    6493   & 70  \\
    6494   & 26  \\
    6495   & 42  \\
    6496   & 80  \\
    6497   & 415 \\
    6498   & 343 \\
    6499   & 100 \\
    6500   & 176 \\
    6501   & 57  \\
    6502   & 89  \\
    6503   & 105 \\
  \end{mytabular}
  \hspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{mytabular}
    6504   & 124 \\
    6505   & 135 \\
    6506   & 30  \\
    6507   & 41  \\
    6508   & 87  \\
    6509   & 50  \\
    6510   & 72  \\
    6511   & 74  \\
    6512   & 29  \\
    6513   & 1   \\
    6514   & 0   \\
  \end{mytabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and here's the result:

[image]

Some comments on other changes I made to the code:

- You can put `\centering` inside a `table` environment to centre its contents, rather than wrapping it within another `center` environment. That is, write

  ```
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}
      % some tabular code
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  ```
- Use the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package, which makes everything look nicer (imo). Feel free to revert, of course.
- Created a `mytabular` environment, which contains the table headings and so on. If you need to change something later, you only need to do it once.

  If you’re bound to the idea of having seven rows per table, then this also makes it fairly easy to reshuffle rows as you want.
- Within the `minipage` environment, the `[t]` option and `\vspace{0pt}` are to ensure that the header of the third table lines up with the first two.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the headers or use a smaller font size or have less columns, but more rows.

I'll show the first solution. It makes use of the `numprint` package to have right-aligned numbers in a centred column and of the `rotating` package. I also improved (at least to my opinion) the general look of the table with the `booktabs` package, suppressing vertical lines and using horizontal rules of different thickness.

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand\myhead[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\hskip-1em\rotatebox[origin =lt]{40}{\rlap{#1}}}}
\usepackage{numprint}

\begin{document}
Interval wertvolle Informationen extrahiert werden kann, betrachten wir die Spalte 6457, in der die Ereignisse anerkannt worden sind.

\begin{table}[H]
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}\centering%\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{cn{4}{1}}}\addlinespace[5ex]
\myhead{Spalte} &\myhead{ Ereignisse} & \myhead{Spalte} & \myhead{Ereignisse} & \myhead{Spalte} & \myhead{Ereignisse} & \myhead{Spalte} & \myhead{Ereignisse} & \myhead{Spalte} & \myhead{Ereignisse} \\[-0.5ex]
\toprule
6480 & 0 & 6487 & 88 & 6494 & 26 & 6501 & 57 & 6508 & 87 \\
\midrule
6481 & 0 & 6488 & 288 & 6495 & 42 & 6502 & 89 & 6509 & 50 \\
\midrule
6482 & 0 & 6489 & 356 & 6496 & 80 & 6503 & 105 & 6510 & 72 \\
\midrule
6483 & 7 & 6490 & 92 & 6497 & 415 & 6504 & 124 & 6511 & 74 \\
\midrule
6484 & 48 & 6491 & 126 & 6498 & 343 & 6505 & 135 & 6512 & 29 \\
\midrule
6485 & 34 & 6492 & 97 & 6499 & 100 & 6506 & 30 & 6513 & 1 \\
\midrule
6486 & 45 & 6493 & 70 & 6500 & 176 & 6507 & 41 & 6514 & 0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]